# Magento 2 Gateway timeout how to resolve

Tags: magento2, cache, varnish, timeout

I have a website on Magento 2 and when I try to access the website, it's really slow and it can take up to 2 minutes to charge a page. When I try to access the admin, either it's really slow like on the website or I get the error

```
504 Gateway Time-out
```

I don't know how to fix it. It seems to be related with varnish but I didn't find anything on the net, I couldn't find the files they talked about.
Thanks for your help

Edit: When I try to access my website, I immediately get the home page with every element on it, but it keeps loading for 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

A few initial checks I would make.

1. **Check your PHP settings:**

> Set the PHP memory limit.
>
> https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034599631-PHP-settings-errors
>
> Our detailed recommendations are:
>
> - Compiling code or deploying static assets, 756M
> - Installing and updating Magento components from Magento Marketplace, 2G
> - Testing, ~3-4G

Check your PHP version is correct, Magento supports PHP 7.4.0.

See: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html#check-php-settings

2. **Ensure you have enabled your store's cache:**

Either via Admin > System > (Tools) Cache Management,

[image: Magento 2 Admin Cache Management]

or via CLI:

```
bin/magento cache:enable
```

3. **Set your Magento mode to production:**

> Production mode also has better performance because static view files
> are populated in the pub/static directory and because of code
> compilation.

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where can I check my php settings? My php version is 7.0. My cache is enabled. I only have the "Page cache" in the invalidated status.

Comment: Magento supports PHP 7.4.0. You can install Magento 2.4.0 with 7.3, but it is not tested or recommended. It is intended for upgrading from Magento 2.3.x to Magento 2.4.0.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html#check-php-settings

Comment: To increase your PHP memory limit:

Log in to your Magento server.
Locate your php.ini file using the following command:

$ php --ini
As a user with root privileges, use a text editor to open the php.ini specified by Loaded Configuration File.

Locate memory_limit.
Change it to a value of 2GB for normal use and debugging.
Save your changes to php.ini and exit the text editor.
Restart your web server.

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034599631-PHP-settings-errors

Comment: memory_limit was at "-1". I put 2GB. I restarted my web server, but nothing changes. It is still really slow.

Comment: Without being able to see your specific server it is hard to tell exactly what is causing the issue. I recommend you contact your web hosting provider to see if they can assist you with speeding up your web server, there may be a setting or two which can be tweaked.

Comment: The server is local, on an LXC on my computer.

Comment: You may want to give docker or valet a try.

Comment: Unfortunatly, that's not my choice. Where I work, we use LXC for our dev environment. We have the same website but on my LXC, the website is really slow whereas on the other's, it's fine.

Comment: Hmmm. Try cleaning up your db: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.cloudways.com/blog/cleanup-magento-database-log/amp/

Comment: I've tried your link but it seems to be for Magento, but I'm on Magento 2 and there is no log cleaning available. When I try to access my website, I immediatly get the home page with every element on it, but it keeps loading for 30 seconds.